How to ignore a source property in AutoMapper
Let's say you have a mapping between a DTO and an entity. Let's say that the DTO contains some property that you do not want to be mapped to the entity. How can I tell Automapper to not map this property? I know that you can tell Automapper to not map a destination property. However, that will not help me, as I want to tell Automapper to not map a source property. Here is an example:
public class MyDto
{
    int A { get; set; }
    int B { get; set; }
    int DoNotMapMeToTheEntity { get; set; }

}

public class MyEntity
{
    int A { get; set; }
    int B { get; set; }
}

As you can see, I do not want Automapper to map DoNotMapMeToTheEntity to MyEntity. Now, you might say that, since DoNotMapMeToTheEntity does not exist in MyEntity, Automapper will not map it, so I have nothing to worry about. But what if in the future someone adds DoNotMapMeToTheEntity to MyEntity. Now Automapper will map it, which I don't want.
I looked for an option to ignore a source property, but could not find it.

CreateMap<MyDto, MyEntity>()             .ForSourceMember(dto => dto.DoNotMapMeToTheEntity, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());

According to the documentation, that does not prevent a source property from being mapped. https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Your question sounds unrealistic. If you worry about when someone possibly adds the DoNotMapMeToTheEntity to MyEntity, why not add the mapping rule to ignore the mapping when someone added it then? Write a comment/ discuss with him/her on the concern/what should be done when adding that property. It is not AutoMapper's role that do something that is possibly/not possibly happen.

@YongShun Actually, one of the purposes of AutoMapper is that you don't need to update the mapping when you add a new property to your entity/dto. However, with that power there should also be a way out, as there will be cases where you definitely know you don't want a property to be mapped.

You could use cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p =>!(p.Name.Equals("DoNotMapMeToTheEntity")); , just remind that "p=>" need a bool value to return:
    public class MySrc
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyDest
    {
        public int A { get; set; } = 1;
        public int B { get; set; } = 1;
        public int C { get; set; } = 1;
    }

var src = new MySrc { A = 5, B = 6, C = 7 };
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MySrc, MyDest>();
    cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p =>!(p.Name.Equals("C"));
});

var mapper = new Mapper(config);
MyDest dest = mapper.Map<MyDest>(src);

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dest));

Test result

When MyDest "C" field doesn't exist

